# Factory returning an undefined object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I am using ionic and angularjs for a mobile app, i am trying to use pull to refresh, but when the refresh(call to doRefresh from UI) is happening, i am getting error

**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFromServer' of undefined"**

the call to getServiceList is working fine when the controller is getting loaded

I am unable to understand why serviceListSerice is returning an undefined object. Please help

My Controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic', 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker'])

.controller('serviceListCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope,$state,serviceListService){


 $scope.doRefresh=function(serviceListService,$scope) {
    serviceListService.getFromServer($scope); //<-this is where i am getting the error
   //$scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
};

serviceListService.getServiceList($scope); //<--- this is called successfully 
                                           //when controller is getting loaded.
})
```

My services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('serviceListService',function() {

    return {


        getServiceList : function($scope) {
            var jsonStr='({"data":[{"id":"1","CircuitID":"130101002","Customer No.":"4160891","CustomerName":"ZZZZ Customer","Last Order":"130101002","ServiceType":"Some String","StartDate":"41878.4125"},'+
            '{"id":"2","CircuitID":"140501837","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140501837","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41859.4083333333"},'+
            '{"id":"3","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"4","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"5","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"6","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"7","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"8","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"9","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"10","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"11","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"12","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"13","CircuitID":"140502362","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"}'+
            ']})';
            console.log(jsonStr);
            var datas= eval(jsonStr);
            $scope.services=datas.data;

        },

        loadMoreServices : function($scope) {
            var updateList='({"data":[{"id":"14","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"15","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"16","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"17","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"18","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"19","CircuitID":"140502362","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"}'+
            ']})';
            $scope.res.push(eval(jsonStr));
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
        },  

        getFromServer:function($scope) {

        var jsonStr='({"data":[{"id":"14","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"15","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"16","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"17","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"18","CircuitID":"140502361","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"},'+
            '{"id":"19","CircuitID":"140502362","Customer No.":"A0156272","CustomerName":"SOME Company","Last Order":"140502361","ServiceType":"SOME STRING","StartDate":"41858.9583333333"}'+
            ']})';
            $scope.res= eval(jsonStr);
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        },


        clearSearch : function($scope) {
            $scope.search = '';
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: How are you calling doRefresh() method?..And do you really need the service and scope as arguments to that method?

Comment: @user700284 , you are right, removing both the parameter worked for me. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are passing serviceListService in $scope function? You don't need it since it is declared in the whole controller. Just try this:

```
$scope.doRefresh = function($scope) {
    serviceListService.getFromServer($scope); //<-this is where i am getting the error
   //$scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
};
```

Comment: also i do not need to send $scope as argument

Comment: @Harshit Hi, I didn't removed $scope from function because in some particular cases you need to pass the scope. It is a very bad practice tho.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to inject the service `serviceListService`  again. Change the code as follows and try!

```
$scope.doRefresh=function($scope) {
    serviceListService.getFromServer($scope); //<-this is where i am getting the error
   //$scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
};
```

Comment: all answers are same so accepted the first answer that was posted

Answer (score 1):

serviceListService when passong to scope function overrides the factory reference and is now a local variable of doRefresh function which obviously will not have them methods of the factory, dont pass it as you dont need to

```
$scope.doRefresh=function($scope) {
    serviceListService.getFromServer($scope); //<-this is where i am getting the error
   //$scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
};
```

Comment: all answers are same so accepted the first answer that was posted

Answer (score 1):

```
 $scope.doRefresh=function($scope) {
    serviceListService.getFromServer($scope); 
   //$scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
};
```

you dont need to pass the dependency to inner functions inside a controller, the factory `serviceListService` is accessible throughout the controller

Comment: all answers are same so accepted the first answer that was posted

Comment: all answers are same so accepted the first answer that was posted

Comment: @Harshit it is about the concept of local variable that over rides the factory reference, concept matters